# Cox models for pooling two clinical trials

Tags: r, survival

I am pooling two similarly designed randomized trials data, each trial with the same intervention and control. I am using a cox model to determine differences in treatment vs control for mortality in the pooled population. How do I ensure that it is appropriate to pool these studies in terms of heterogenity? Do I stratify the final cox model by clinical trial? Or do I assess for interaction by trial status before building the model? Is there an R test for heterogeneity by trial?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by formally pooling the studies, that you can't achieve by analyzing and discussing them separately?

Comment: One of the studies was underpowered. Other was appropriately powered. Want to assess if both were responding similar to treatment (looking for interaction)

Comment: So your real interest is not so much in pooling the studies, but rather in assessing whether the designs had some systematic heterogeneity? What sources or kinds of heterogeneity would you postulate?

Comment: Correct. Study one had patients with kidney disease and study two had patients without. I'm really interested in if kidney disease caused any heterogeneity. Both trials have large number  of patients but one was statistically significant for outcomes and one was not, and I believe the own that wasn't was underpowered. I want to assess if the underpowered one was responding similar to the powered one, as it's results was trending in that direction

Comment: My thought was to pool the studies and see if trial status was an interaction with outcome. Thoughts on this?

Comment: You would seem to have an [identification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_identification_problem), in that case. Imagine you *did* pool the data, and included indicator variables for *study* and *presence of kidney disease*. Per your report, these two variables would have the same values (all 1's for study A, all 0's for study B), and you could not discriminate some unknown study effect (i.e., A vs B contrast) from the effect of kidney disease. Do you have a measure of *severity* of kidney disease in the first study? Perhaps you could regress outcome on this measure.